# DLookup function not working in subform, MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a main form "fmEmpHWList2" inside it there are two subforms. In the subform "frmSWList2" I have textfields that I'm using Dlookup functions to get values from a table. 
When I tested this on the subform alone everything worked. But when I brought the subform into the main form I get the "#Name?" error.

Here is my current code within the mainform that gives me the error and I need to fix:

```
=DLookUp("Version","EmpSWSum","Software = '7-Zip' AND EmpID=" & [Forms]![fmEmpHWList2]![frmSWList2].[Form]![EmpID])
```

In the subform alone this code works

```
=DLookUp("Version","EmpSWSum","Software = 'ADG R4i CSDB Client' AND EmpID=" & [Forms]![frmSWList2]![EmpID])
```

Things to note: EmpID is a number

I appreciate your taking the time to help me solve this

Comment: Hi. This link might be helpful. http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm. It sounds like you need to do the following: `Me!Subform1.Form!ControlName`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I've also referenced that form multiple times and tried man different combinations without success.

Comment: @RyanWildry `Me` is not a valid reference inside a Control Source property... at least Access always automatically wraps it like `[Me]` and then returns an error.  Is the table you linked to for referencing within VBA modules?

Comment: I suggest simplifying the debugging process by 1) Placing a new textbox on the main form. 2) Set the new textbox Control Source property to `=[subformCONTROLname].[Name]`. 3) View the main form.  The new textbox should simply show the name of the subform control.  If that works, then add a 2nd new textbox with `=[subformCONTROLname]![EmpID]`.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend naming the subform container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrSWList. Then code in a main form control:

`=DLookUp("Version","EmpSWSum","Software = '7-Zip' AND EmpID=" & [ctrSWList]![EmpID])`

However, if this expression is in a control on the subform and you want to reference another control on the subform, no need for the form names and classes prefix.

`=DLookUp("Version","EmpSWSum","Software = '7-Zip' AND EmpID=" & [EmpID])`

That should also work if the subform is opened as a standalone.

Comment: I renamed my subform to ctrSWList and copied your code in. It didn't work. In the subform there is an EmpID text box named "EmpID" I draw the EmpIDs from. So this should work. Like I said it works in stand alone as a subform/form on it's own.

It's when I imbed the subform the issue arises.

Something I didn't think about, the software list is on a tab "SWpg1" and that could be a problem.

But for testing purposes I moved one of my fields out of the tab and into the main subform to see if your code would work and it didn't. thank you @June7

Comment: @MaxineHammett What do you mean by "renamed my subform"?  In other words, there are two possible things to rename: 1) The actual subform object (really just a normal Form) that is listed in the Access Navigation Pane, and 2) the Subform control on the main form. It has a Name property and a Source Object property.  June7 means to rename _only_ the subform **control** (so that its Name and Source Object properties are different), NOT to rename both.  The DLookUp expression should reference the control name and not the actual subform name.

Comment: @CPerkins I changed the DLookUp like you suggested =DLookUp("Version","EmpSWSum","Software = '7-Zip' AND EmpID=" & [frmSWList2]![Employee]) but still recieved the Name? error. Employee is the name of the textbox, EmpID is the value of the textbox. They are in the form frmSWList2. Am I referencing it right?

Comment: What is the name of the subform container control? Is it also frmSWList2? I suggested naming the container control different from the form object.

Comment: @June here is how I have it broken down Master form = fmEmpHWList
Subform = frmSWList
Tab group = TabGrp
Tab page = SWpg1
Cntrl = EmpID Thank you for you help and patience

Comment: Yes, but what is the name of the subform container control? I suggest it not be frmSWList if the form is named frmSWList.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and made a function instead of doing a DLookUp. I think it's a better approach. I'm loading the function in the form open even.

```
1 Function RunParameterQuery_DAO(Asset As String, Software As String, sTextBox As String) As String
2   ' Comments: Runs a query containing parameters
3   Const cstrQueryName As String = "qrySWVers"
4   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
5   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
6   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
7   
8   Set dbs = CurrentDb()
9   Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQueryName)
10   qdf.Parameters("asset") = Asset
11   qdf.Parameters("name") = Software
12   ' Open recordset on the query
13   Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
14   Do While Not rst.EOF
15     Me.Controls(sTextBox).Value = rst![SWVer]
16     rst.MoveNext
17   Loop
18    MsgBox (Me.Controls(sTextBox).Value)
19   rst.Close
20   qdf.Close
21   dbs.Close
22 End Function
```

To run it

```
Call RunParameterQuery_DAO("L52651", "TortoiseSVN", "TortoiseSVN")
```

Comment: Wait this isn't working. My textbox isn't bound and I'm calling my function in the Control Source as =RunParameterQuery_DAO("Me.[AssetID]","7-Zip","txt7Zip") Nothings showing up and I don't understand why.

Your help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Why would a custom function be better than the intrinsic function? Issue is still how to correctly reference the objects and controls. Which Open event - the main form or subform? You are giving TortoiseSVN as name of textbox in the function argument.

Comment: You are passing a string `"Me.[AssetID]"`, but there is nothing that will magically translate an explicit string value into a valid reference.  Yes, Access will do that for certain special cases and functions, but not just anywhere.  I agree with June7 comment, but at least try removing the quotes and Me reference: `=RunParameterQuery_DAO([AssetID],"7-Zip","txt7Zip")`  I assume [AssetID] is a control on the form.

Comment: The open even was the subform. I tried just using [AssetID] and it didn't work. Somethings wrong with this function and I don't understand what. The immediete window returns the values if I use the debug.print statements, I just cant get the value into the textbox.value. Like you said a reference problem into the control issue. @June @C Perkins